# Composition of bounded operator and compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

In Hilbert space $H$, is it true that the composition of operators  $ST$ and $TS$ of the bounded operator $S$ and the compact operator $T$ are compact?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes (and more generally in a Banach space).  If $B$ is the closed unit ball, 
$\overline{TB}$ is compact, so $STB \subseteq S(\overline{TB})$ which is compact (in a Hausdorff space, a continuous image of a compact set is compact).
Therefore $ST$ is a compact operator.

$SB \subseteq \|S\| B$, so $TSB \subseteq \|S\| TB \subseteq \|S\| \overline{TB}$ which is compact, so $TS$ is a compact operator.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.

Comment: I believe you do not need the space to be Hausdorff in order for the continuous image of a compact set to be compact