# If an operator in $X$ with compact resolvent is bounded, $X$ must be finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, compact-operators

In Kato's book, this is problem 6.30. I have been looking at different ways of proving this. Here is my attempt;

**Theorem**
If an operator $A$ in $X$ with compact resolvent is bounded, $X$ must be finite dimensional.

**Proof**
Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional, and let $\{e_i\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a basis for $X$. As $A$ has compact resolvent, its spectrum is of isolated eigenvalues with finite multiplicities. Therefore, let $x \in X$ be an eigenfunction of $A$, with $Ax= \lambda x$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.  Then we have that 
\begin{equation}
||Ax||_X = ||\lambda x ||_X = |\lambda| ||x||_X =|\lambda| ||\sum_{n=0}^\infty  a_i e_i||_X \leq |\lambda| (\max |a_i|) ||\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ e_i||_X.
\end{equation}

As $X$ is infinite dimensional $||\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ e_i||_X$ is infinite. This contradicts that $A$ us bounded.

...

Now, I think my last sentence is dodgy. Can anyone offer any clarification or a more natural way to prove it?

Kindest regards, C

Comment: This doesn't contradict boundedness.  All you say is that $\|Ax\|_X\leq\infty$, a fact which is true for unbounded and bounded operators alike.

Answer (score 5):

There exists $c$ such that $B=(A-cI)^{-1}$ is compact, (definition of resolvent) since $A$ is bounded, $A-cI$ is bounded and $(A-cI)(A-cI)^{-1}=I$ is compact. We deduce that the space is finite dimensional.

[Composition of bounded operator and compact operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278071/composition-of-bounded-operator-and-compact-operators)

Comment: How do you deduce A is finite-dimensional?

Comment: I think you meant to write "$I$ is compact" as opposed to "$I$ is bounded".

Comment: If the identity is compact, $I(B(0,1))=B(0,1)$ is compact. This implies that $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thank you so much